# To save gazebo setting and launch

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm working with ROS kinect on Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm trying to make my own navigation file based on turtlebot.

As far as I know, it is essential to make the robot be in the same place and pose with these of when it started to make its map.

But what I can do now is just,

> roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch

Of course I can insert `garage willow` in gazebo after I launch the above,

but, I can't load the file I saved which has turtlebot and garage willow.

What I want to do is,

`to make the turtlebot is in the garage willow filed with the same place and pose with those of when I made the map of garage`

Anyone who can give me help?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342354/to-save-gazebo-setting-and-launch/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I can't load the file I saved which has turtlebot and garage willow.

When saving a world in Gazebo you don't save it with the robot in it, you have to create your world with only your obstacles and then save the world. To add your robot in a world you use a service : `/gazebo/spawn_urdf_model` that is called when you use the node `spawn_model`(you can find it [here in the kobuki.launch](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator/blob/indigo/turtlebot_gazebo/launch/includes/kobuki.launch.xml) that is included from `turtlebot_world.launch`).

To tell which world you want to use there is the argument `world_file` in the `turtlebot_world.launch` so you just have to specify it when using `roslaunch` :

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch world_file:=/PATH/TO/YOUR/WORLD
```

You can also modify the launch file to change the default value, or in that case the launch file use the environment variable `TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE` so you can set it in your terminal to the path of your world file using :

```
export TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE = /PATH/TO/YOUR/WORLD
```

> to make the turtlebot is in the garage willow filed with the same place and pose with those of when I made the map of garage

Now when you call the service to spawn the model you can specify the position you want for the robot:

```
 <node name="spawn_turtlebot_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
        args="-x 0 -y 0 -Y -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model mobile_base"/>
```

You have to use the arguments `-x, -y, -z, -R, -P, -Y` to set x, y, z and the roll, pitch and yaw of our robot.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2020-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1